# How can I pipe to sed?

Tags: sed

I want to print a line from one file and use that as the input for a line replacement in another file.

```
sed -n '12p' FILE1 | sed -i '12c\ STDIN' FILE2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: So, you want to replace line 12 in `FILE2` with line 12 from `FILE1`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any implementation of sed that supports reading from standard input for the `c` command, but in GNU sed you could use the `r` command with pseudo-filename `/dev/stdin`, followed by `d` to delete the original line:

```
... | sed -i '12{
r /dev/stdin
d
}' FILE2
```

or, more compactly using `-e` to chain expressions

```
... | sed -i -e '12{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' FILE2
```

The braces group the `r` and `d` commands so that they are both executed for the address `12`. You can't simply use `12{r /dev/stdin; d;}` because the `; d;}` will be parsed as part of the argument to `r`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll need to look into trying  to understand the use of quotes and brackets here.

Comment: @paradroid I have expanded the answer with a note about the syntax

Comment: `r` is standard, it's not GNU specific. `-i` is a GNUism but found in  several other implementations these days.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks - it was actually the `/dev/stdin` rather than the `r` command that I was flagging as potentially GNU specific; the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) describes it as *"a GNU sed extension"*

Answer (score 1):

No, `sed` interprets piped data as where to operate and never as replacement patterns. If you provide a filename, the pipe will be ignored. You will have to use command substitution instead:

```
sed "12c$(sed -n 12p FILE1)" FILE2
```

Or make some detour via named pipes:

```
mkfifo sedpipe
sed -n 12p FILE1 >sedpipe &
sed -i "12c$(cat sedpipe)" FILE2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` and creating a backup file at the same time.

```
sed -i.bak "12c$(sed -n '12p' file1)" file2
```

Or a portable option

```
sed -i.bak "12s/.*/$(sed -n '12p' file1)/" file2
```

Comment: `-i` is not POSIX, so the portability is not necessarily given with your alternative.